# How to remove array from a 2D array of arrays in Javascript (and/or with Lodash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, lodash

I have an array of arrays

```
let arr = [ [2, 3], [2, 3] ];
```

I tried using the Lodash ._uniq function

```
let newArr = _.uniq(arr);
```

but when I do this

```
console.log(newArr)
```

My result is still

```
[2, 3],
[2, 3]
```

This is the CDN I'm linking to in my HTML file

```
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"
```

I'd like newArr to contain just this:

```
[2, 3]
```

Will Lodash work for this or do I need to try something else?

Comment: `_.uniqWith(arr, _.isEqual)` should work

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. That's giving me what I need. Many thanks.